# Cassandra insert/update if not exists or field=value

Tags: cassandra, conditional-statements, cql, upsert

I would like to do in a single operation an insert if a record doesn't exist, or update only if a field of the row has a certain value.

Imagine the table:

```
CREATE TABLE (id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, field_a VARCHAR, field_b VARCHAR);
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field_a='test' WHERE id='an-id' IF NOT EXISTS OR IF field_b='AVALUE';
```

Doing INSERT/UPDATE on a single statement that insert the record if `field_b` has value `AVALUE` or create a new row if a row doesn't already exists, but in case a row is in the table having `field_b` with a different value failing the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table SET field_a='test' WHERE id='an-id'
IF NOT EXISTS OR IF field_b='AVALUE';
```

There are a few of nuances here.  First it's important to remember that when doing a compare-and-set (CAS) operation in CQL, the syntax and capabilities between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are *not* the same.

Case-in-point, the `IF NOT EXISTS` conditional is valid for `INSERT`, but not for `UPDATE`.  On the flip-side, `IF EXISTS` is valid for `UPDATE`, but not for `INSERT`.

Secondly, `OR` is not a valid operator in CQL `WHERE` or in CAS operation conditionals.

Third, using `UPDATE` with `IF EXISTS` short-circuits any subsequent conditionals.  So `UPDATE` can *either* use `IF EXISTS` *or* `IF (condition) [ AND (another condition) ]`, but not both.

Considering these points, it would seem one approach here would be to split the statement into two:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id,field_a) VALUES ('a1','test') IF NOT EXISTS;
```

And:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field_a='test' WHERE id='an-id' IF field_b='AVALUE';
```

These are both valid CQL.  However, that doesn't really help this situation.  An alternative would be to build this logic on the application side.  Technically, read-before-write approaches are considered anti-patterns in Cassandra, in-built CAS operations not withstanding due to their use of lightweight transactions.

Perhaps something like `SELECT field_a,field_b FROM my_table WHERE id='an-id';` is enough to answer whether it exists as well as what the value of `field_b` is, thus triggering an additional write?  There's a potential for a race condition here, so I'd closely examine the business requirements to see if something like this could work.

Comment: Thank you, very detailed. It seems it is something that can't be done with a single statement. I was thinking to have two queries too, but with a difference with your suggestion, I was thinking to execute `INSERT INTO my_table (id, field_b) VALUES ('a1', 'AVALUE') IF NOT EXISTS;` and then `UPDATE my_table SET field_a='test' WHERE id ='an-id' IF field_b='AVALUE';`. In this way if the row doesn't exists it is created with the correct value for `field_b` (this statement acting like default values for the id), and then the rest can be done with the update. Do you see any issues?

Comment: @rascio I think that's a good approach.  Other than the potential race condition (another client running the same ops on the same key) that I already mentioned, I think this is worth trying, and then keep an eye on it for a while just to watch for potential anomalies.